# Node.js displaying data using node-rest-client from Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-rest-client

I am new to Node.js and I am stuck with small issue. My api is returning JSon but I am not able to see JSon in data or response.

```
router.get('/search/:id', function(req, res){client.get("http://localhost:3000/api/search/5600678e1c76b4680e0d6544", function(data, response){
         
        console.log(data);
        console.log(response);

res.render('test', {test: data,  user : req.user , title : 'Home'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add what is the console output of data and response?

Comment: Also, please include what `client` is.

Comment: @AnotherDev looks like this is client: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client

Comment: Yes I am using node-rest-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I understood you wrong here another way of how to do it using the npm module `request`

```js
var request = require('request');

router.get('/search/:id', function(req, res) {
  request('http://localhost:3000/api/search/5600678e1c76b4680e0d6544', function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body)
      var data = body;
      res.render('test', {
        test: data,
        user: req.user,
        title: 'Home'
      });
    } else {
      res.end('Error: ' + error);
    }
  });
});
```

If this is not working than maybe the error is on `localhost:3000` not returning anything.

Comment: On request to /search/:id, I want to pull data from /api/search/:id and display.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this :

```
console.log(data);
```

"data" is a json formated object.

Try to use this :

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

To see a json object.